# Looking for a terminal download manager

Tags: terminal, software-rec, download

I am looking for a download manager running in CLI (terminal).

Tool should solve the following purpose.

1. Take a list of YouTube URL as input / take a URL-list from a file.
2. Should pause and resume download when the network connection is interrupted.
3. Should run in terminal. I am running this on a headless media server.

I use a `youtube-dl` nodejs script now. But the script lacks connection monitoring and download integrity check, download resume feature.

I tried Extreme Download manager and it wouldn't run headless.

Any inputs for achieving the same is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two  `while` loop in `bash` should be enough:

```
while ! youtube-dl --batch-file /tmp/yt -i -c --socket-timeout 5; do while ! ping -c 1 -W 1 google.com; do echo "Network interface may down, please check your network"; sleep 10; done; echo "Network up but got url failed before, re-loop file after 5 seconds."; sleep 5; done
```

**Explanation:**

- `youtube-dl` is python package available to install via ordinary
  package manager such as `apt`.
- `/tmp/yt` file contains list of urls line by line.
- `-i` means continue pick next url in the file if encounter url invalid error (but not socket error, which will go into `ping`'s "failed & wait for network up" loop)
- `-c` means force resume of partially downloaded files. The filename should has consistent format for resume to work (i.e. you can't change `youtube-dl` format next time and expect resume to work). I personally use `-o './%(title)s-%(upload_date)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s'` format
- I personally also add `--no-mtime` to ensure the file "touch" (useful if I want to list file sort by download time instead of video update time).

Answer (score 1):

Any command-line [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) client should be useful. On POSIX systems, consider [GNU wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) (and, if the protocol is [FTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol), one of the numerous FTP command line clients such as [ncftp](http://www.ncftp.com/)).

You could also code something by yourself, using some HTTP client library like [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) (and many scripting languages, e.g. Python, Guile, Perl, etc... have numerous HTTP client facilities). Be sure to learn a bit more about [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) and its [cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie).

You could find (for Linux) some youtube specific command-line tools.

Comment: wget is not technically a download manager nor they identify themself as such

Comment: You don't define what is a download manager. I never heard that expression before (specially with headless)

Comment: @Basile *A download manager is a type of software that manages the downloading of files from the Internet, which may be built into a web browser, or as a standalone program.* Maybe try Wikipedia next time?

Comment: On Linux, GNU `wget`